# How to accept 'sigplusweb' addon using selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

I am using selenium to automate my web page.

At a specific page i have to accept `sigplusweb` addon in my browser.

How do I accept this addon in my script.

I am not able to reach at any point.

Comment: Could you provide example of your script and give information about what you tried so far ?

Comment: Hi @YanBrunet, The issue has been resolved. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Put "about:config" in browser window , and preference value of 'sigPlusWeb' addon.

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("preference", 2);
```

It will automatically accept addon when script run.